# Access session variable of one site in another

Tags: asp.net, .net

Can i access session variable of one site in another(same IIS)

site1:

aaa.xxx.com
Session["name"]="balaji"

site2:

bbb.xxx.com
string name=Session["name"].ToString()

Is it possible?

Comment: I dont think it is possible to share across different application until you preserve it in database

Comment: No, you cannot. why would you want to do that?

Comment: You could store the session in database or state-server (used for web farms)
  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178586.ASPX

Comment: @TimSchmelter he wants to share a variable. why let him deal with serialization and network traffic while he can share them via file/memprymapped file

Comment: We are having two websites(c# and VB.NET) and single DB. User must able to login from any one of the site

Comment: Because a memory mapped file approach would be much more complex and would prevent to chose a different session-state later. Also, a database or state-server is much more scalable.

Comment: @balaji: then use an ASP.NET membership provider that uses the same users. For example a `SqlServerMemberShipProvider` that stores the users in a sql-server database.

Answer (score 1):

> ASP.NET session state enables you to store and retrieve values for a
>   user as the user navigates ASP.NET pages in a Web application. HTTP is
>   a stateless protocol. This means that a Web server treats each HTTP
>   request for a page as an independent request. The server retains no
>   knowledge of variable values that were used during previous requests.
>   ASP.NET session state identifies requests from the same browser during
>   a limited time window as a session, and provides a way to persist
>   variable values for the duration of that session.

source : [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved using Query String.

Call the second site URL with a query string with it. `http:\\bbb.xxx.com?name=balaji`

Handle the query string in the second site.

More info - [How to use Query String](http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2012/10/query-string-in-aspnet-example-c-vbnet.html)